# Docker : Ubuntu/Shiny R : error when I try to run my own custom environment

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, rstudio

I’m quite new at docker, and I’d like to create a docker environement with exactly the same configuration as my production server one. My docker will be used as a local development environement for one specific R Shiny Server application.

Here are my settings :

```
I’m working locally on Windows 7
Server is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Server R version : 3.5.1
```

I was managed to use rocker/rstudio, but it doesn’t allow me to deal with R versions; furthermore, it’s based on Debian distribution.

So, quite innocently, I tried to build my own Dockerfile based on already existing Dockerfiles, to perform installation from Ubuntu -> R -> RStudio + Shiny server.

My Dockerfile is built successfully, but I get the following error when I try to run it with the following command line :

```
docker run -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=Mypswd -v /c/Users/njeanray/Documents/Myproject:/home/rstudio/myproject rstudio:R3.5.1
```

[image]

Please, find my Dockerfile at this place :

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/972d94d2ec730ecb8afbc2b315c8fbb020200429094458/3c31aa

It’s quite weird because I’ve taken the code from Dockerfile rocker/rstudio, and running rocker/rstudio works…
How can I manage to run my environment from Ubuntu 18.04, with R 3.5.1 and RStudio ?
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Many thanks in advance,

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I created a docker image from the Dockerfile shared by you. It is hosted on https://hub.docker.com/r/aktechthoughts/r-studio-docker. 
It is working fine.

Comment: Well, thanks ! I will try it ASAP. But did you perform any modification on it ?

Comment: I used the same Dockerfile.

Comment: I just tried to run your image, and it works perfectly. I can't understand why I'm not manage to run it myself from the dockerfile I just built. Do you have an idea on why I get this error message ? I'm woring on Windows 7 if it can help

Comment: I created the image on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It compiled for a long time then worked.

Comment: Yes, it compiles also on my computer. But I can't run it without having the error mentionned below.